# print text show the file path using Java

Tags: java, algorithm, checksum, fileutils, apache-stringutils

I need a java method to check text

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: There are tools to do this already.  Usually using shell scripts but you can call them from Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare size file by file, saving the equal size files into an arraylist and then printing this ArrayList info.

Is a very simple and rude method, maybe if u have a folder with lot of links or things like this will not be working ok.

If u want to investigate more, u can use checksum to check this, but you need knowledge of this aspect.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in Java, you can use commons.io Apache library, with the method *iterateFiles* to get the files inside the directory, and the method *contentEquals* to check if two files have the same content.

## Imports

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
```

## Code

```
final String path = "C:/...";
List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
Iterator iterator = FileUtils.iterateFiles(new File(path), null, false);
while(iterator.hasNext()){
    // Compare with the rest of the files in the array
    final File file = iterator.next();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.size(); i++) {
        if (FileUtils.contentEquals(file, files.get(i))) {
            // Here you can show the file path name
        }
    }

    // Add the file to the array
    files.add(file);
}
```

Comment: Thank you Victor for your nice answer. Could you please write the rest of the code as i am beginner in Java.